# Create one FormControl for multiple input fields

Tags: angular-material2, angular5

I have a Form, that contains an variable number of input fields. They all look like the following.

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
   <input  matInput placeholder="" type="text"
           [formControl]="mFormControl">
</mat-form-field>
```

My Form Control looks like:

```
mFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.pattern("mypattern")
]);`
```

The problem is, that the form control validates every input field to wrong, when just one is wrong. I want, that just the Input Field, which contains the wrong text, is marked as wrong.

Has someone an idea how to archieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FormBuilder

Html

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="mFormGroup" style="width: 100%;">
   <input  matInput placeholder="" type="text"
           [formControl]="mFormGroup.controls['firstName']">
</mat-form-field>
```

Typescript

```
this.mFormGroup = formBuilder.group({
                        firstName: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
                  });
```